# Calling function from one class in another in C++

Tags: c++

So, I am writing a program in C++ that has a function in the Sort class that I wish to call in the Main class. The function has several data members used that are present in that class, that are not present in the Main class and I keep getting a C2660 error, that "Function does not take 0 arguments". Is there a way (short of writing a bunch of getters and setters) to resolve this?

```
#include "Sort.h"
#include "Timer.h"
using namespace std;
int main
{
Sort *sort = new Sort();
Timer ti;
sort->SetRandomSeed(12345);

sort->InitArray();
cout << "starting InsertionSort" << endl;
ti.Start();
sort->InsertionSort();
ti.End();
cout << "Insertion sort duration: " << ti.DurationInMilliSeconds() << "ms" << endl;

//sort->InitList();
//cout << "starting InsertionSortList()" << endl;
//ti.Start();
//sort->InsertionSortList();
//ti.End();
//cout << "Insertion sort list duration: " << ti.DurationInMilliSeconds() << "ms" << endl;

sort->InitArray();
cout << "starting SelectionSort" << endl;
ti.Start();
sort->SelectionSort();
ti.End();
cout << "SelectionSort duration: " << ti.DurationInMilliSeconds() << "ms" << endl;

sort->InitArray();
cout << "starting MergeSort" << endl;
ti.Start();
sort->MergeSort();
ti.End();
cout << "MergeSort duration: " << ti.DurationInMilliSeconds() << "ms" << endl;

sort->InitArray();
cout << "starting QuickSort" << endl;
ti.Start();
sort->QuickSort();
ti.End();
cout << "QuickSort duration: " << ti.DurationInMilliSeconds() << "ms" << endl;

sort->InitVector();
cout << "starting std::sort() of Vector<int>" << endl;
ti.Start();
sort->VectorSort();
ti.End();
cout << "std::sort() duration: " << ti.DurationInNanoSeconds() << "ns" << endl;

delete sort;

cout << endl <<"Press [Enter] key to exit";
getchar();

}


Sort.cpp
//const int for array
int num = 10000000;
int val = 10000;
//array
int *tmpArray, *qArr, *insArr, *selArr, *mergArr = NULL;
int low, high;

//duration for timer
int duration = 0;

Sort::Sort()
{
}


Sort::~Sort()
{
}

void Sort::InitArray()
{
//int for index
int i = 0;
tmpArray = new int[num];
qArr = new int[num];
insArr = new int[num];
selArr = new int[num];
mergArr = new int[num];
//fill temp array with sequential numbers
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    tmpArray[i] = 1 + rand() % val;
}

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    qArr[i] = tmpArray[i];
    insArr[i] = tmpArray[i];
    selArr[i] = tmpArray[i];
    mergArr[i] = tmpArray[i];
}
low = qArr[0];
high = qArr[num - 1];
int n = sizeof(tmpArray) / sizeof(tmpArray[0]);
}

void Sort::InitVector()
{
vector<int> v(num);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::rand);
}

void Sort::InitList()
{
// A set to store values
std::list<int> l;
// Loop until we get 50 unique random values
while (l.size() < num)
{
    l.push_back(1 + rand() % val);
}
for (int n : l) {
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
}

//setting seed
void Sort::SetRandomSeed(unsigned int seed)
{
seed = rand();
}


void Sort::InsertionSort()
{
int i, key, j;

for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    key = insArr[i];
    j = i - 1;

    /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
    greater than key, to one position ahead
    of their current position */
    while (j >= 0 && insArr[j] > key)
    {
        insArr[j + 1] = insArr[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    insArr[j + 1] = key;
}
delete[] insArr;
insArr = NULL;
}

int Sort::partition(int qArr[], int low, int high)
{
int pivot = qArr[high];    // pivot
int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element

for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
{
    // If current element is smaller than or
    // equal to pivot
    if (qArr[j] <= pivot)
    {
        i++;    // increment index of smaller element
        swap(&qArr[i], &qArr[j]);
    }
}
swap(&qArr[i + 1], &qArr[high]);
return (i + 1);
}

void  Sort::QuickSort(int qArr[], int low, int high)
{
if (low < high)
{
    /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
    at right place */
    int pi = partition(qArr, low, high);

    // Separately sort elements before
    // partition and after partition
    QuickSort(qArr, low, pi - 1);
    QuickSort(qArr, pi + 1, high);
}
delete[] qArr;
qArr = NULL;
}

void Sort::SelectionSort()
{
int i, j, min_idx;
// One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
    min_idx = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        if (selArr[j] < selArr[min_idx])
            min_idx = j;

    // Swap the found minimum element with the first element
    swap(&selArr[min_idx], &selArr[i]);
}
delete[] selArr;
selArr = NULL;
}

void Sort::swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
int temp = *xp;
*xp = *yp;
*yp = temp;
}

void Sort::VectorSort()
{
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void Sort::merge(int mergArr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
int i, j, k;
int n1 = m - l + 1;
int n2 = r - m;
int* L;
int* R;
/* create temp arrays */
L = new int[n1];
R = new int[n2];

/* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    L[i] = mergArr[l + i];
for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    R[j] = mergArr[m + 1 + j];

/* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
while (i < n1 && j < n2)
{
    if (L[i] <= R[j])
    {
        mergArr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        mergArr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
are any */
while (i < n1)
{
    mergArr[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
are any */
while (j < n2)
{
    mergArr[k] = R[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
}

void Sort::MergeSort(int mergArr[], int l, int r)
{
if (l < r)
{
    // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
    // large l and h
    int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
    // Sort first and second halves
    MergeSort(mergArr, l, m);
    MergeSort(mergArr, m + 1, r);
    merge(mergArr, l, m, r);
}
delete[] mergArr;
mergArr = NULL;
}


Sort.h
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

#pragma once
class Sort
{
public:
Sort();
~Sort();

void InitArray();

void InitVector();
void InitList();
void SetRandomSeed(unsigned int seed);  
int n, right, left, l, r, m;
vector<int> v;
void InsertionSort();
int partition(int qArr[], int low, int high);
void QuickSort(int qArr[], int low, int high);
void swap(int * xp, int * yp);
void VectorSort();
void MergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r);
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
void SelectionSort();
};
```

Ignoring the Timer class (those are all good) here is the rest of the code. The C2660 errors are shown for the sort->MergeSort() and sort->QuickSort() calls in main.

Comment: Do you know what the difference between a "member" and an "argument" is? Because this shows a bunch of arguments, not members.

Comment: The function used in Sort.cpp uses (as arguements) a number of data members (2 ints and an int array) that are present in Sort that are NOT present in Main. Thus the purpose of asking whether getters and setters were needed to create versions of said data members in Main

Comment: Those *shouldn't* be arguments, then. Why are they arguments if they're members, which would be accessible from within the function?

Comment: What you have provided so far leaves a lot of questions. Could we have a [mcve] to try and clear things up?

Comment: Because it calls itself recursively, with variations to the arguments

Comment: Important terminology note: those are not "members". Members would be accessible from the class itself, and from your description, would be related to an instance of the class; those are file-scoped variables (I'm not sure if there's a specific term for those in C++), and are shared between all instances since they're just a local variable in the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issues myself. I created helper functions in the Sort class that have no arguments and call the functions themselves to use in the main. Helper Functions shown below.

```
Sort.cpp
//method for Main to run to prevent C2660 errors
void Sort::mergeHelper()
{
    MergeSort(mergArr, l, r);//call merge sort method
}

//method for Main to run to prevent C2660 errors
void Sort::quickHelper()
{
     QuickSort(qArr, low, high);//call quick sort method
}

int Main
{
    sort->quickHelper();
    sort->mergeHelper();
}
```